# columnas vacías de un grid de kendo con asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, telerik

Estoy generando un grid de kendo telerik con asp.net core, traigo la lista del servidor pero no los muestra correctamente en las columnas

en la clase llamo al servicio, que me trae los registros de la base de datos

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {

        Language = new List<LanguageResponseModel.Data>();
        var LanguagesResponse = await _languageService.GetAllLanguagesAsync();
        if (LanguagesResponse.IsSuccess)
        {
            Language = LanguagesResponse.Datas;
        }
        var dataLanguage = Language.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return new JsonResult(dataLanguage);
    }
```

en la vista integro el grid de kendo

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<APP.PS.WEB.Data.Models.Language.LanguageResponseModel.Data>().Name("grid")
                    .Editable()
                    .Scrollable()
                    .ToolBar(x => {
                        x.Create();
                    })
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(column => column.Name);
                        columns.Bound(column => column.Culture);
                        columns.Bound(column => column.FlagName);
                        columns.Command(column =>
                        {
                            column.Edit();
                            column.Destroy();
                        });
                    })
                    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                           .Read(r => r.Url("/Languages?handler=Read").Data("forgeryToken"))
                           .Update(u => u.Url("/Languages?handler=Update").Data("forgeryToken"))
                           .Create(c => c.Url("/Languages?handler=Create").Data("forgeryToken"))
                           .Destroy(d => d.Url("/Languages?handler=Destroy").Data("forgeryToken"))
                           .Model(m =>
                           {
                               m.Id(id => id.Id);
                               m.Field(f => f.Name).Editable(true);
                               m.Field(f => f.Culture).Editable(true);
                           })
                           .Events(events => events.Error("grid_error")) // Handle the "error" event.
                        .PageSize(10)
                    )
                    .Pageable()
                )
```

Si obtiene los registros, pero no los muestra en la tabla

[image: genera las filas de los registros y agrega sus botones, pero no muestra la información del los campos]